# Is there is a way to get Commits by datetime In bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Is it possible to get commits on Bitbucket by datetime filter using their REST API v1.0 ? I read the entire documentation of the Bitbucket API, but I couldn't find anything related. I'm asking perhaps I did miss something. Thank you!

API I am using to get Commits from bitbucket `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{0}/repos/{1}/commits`

[BitBucket API Document](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.7.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45568367054656)

Answer (score -1):

Looking at their docs you can apply filtering but it's not very clear.

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/filtering

You can apply filtering such as

```
updated_on <= 2015-03-04
```

Comment: This is for api v2 still I have tried using it but its not working.